# Is there any way to share the object between two different process in perl on windows environment?

Tags: windows, perl, object, process, parallel-processing

I am trying to execute two parallel different perl script on Windows.I am create one object in first script. And I want to use that object in another process.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your content quality up

Comment: Read [perlipc](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node=perlman%3Aperlipc)

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what you want to do and which object is affected. Improve your question with more details to get a more specific answer.

You could dump your object using [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) or [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) (or many other formats, but those are the most common) in one process, transmit it to the other process (via disk, database, memcache, network, IPC) and recreate the object in the second process. This one will work for all objects without external dependencies (like database connections, open files, etc.). Try to avoid doing it for non-selfmade modules and be careful when doing it with your own modules.

You could also use shared memory (for example [`Win32::MMF`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::MMF), but never tried it myself) while writing your own modules, but remember that shared memory is (very) slow, at least on Linux.

Comment: Perl also has `Storable` which allows object serialisation. This isn't portable, but is at least part of the core distribution (where `JSON` isn't).

Comment: I have never been able to get `Win32::MMF` to install properly. It builds fine, but perl crashes several times trying to execute the tests. I've used various Strawberry and ActiveState builds of perl and got the same result every time